# Updating Specific Properties in Javascript Object Array in React/Lodash/Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, replace, traversal

I'm currently using React/Redux to update my redux store.

Currently I have a list of data called `supplies` that looks something like this:

```
    { id:1, type: "All", checked: true },
    { id:2, type: 'Notepad', checked: true },
    { id:3, type: 'Laptop', checked: true },
    { id:4, type: 'Pencil', checked: true },
    { id:5, type: 'Bus Ticket', checked: true }
```

When I click a checkbox, I pass in the current `supplies`, the check boolean status and id that was checked to the action creator.

From the action creator, I want to update the Supplies data with the status of the new id, which will then be passed to the reducer. I'm handling the updated changes in the action creator rather than the reducer since I'm not sure how to update it properly in the redux store reducer.

I understand you can find a specific Id like so:

```
obj = _.find(myArray, function(obj) { return obj.id == '1' })
```

But if I wanted only wanted to update id of 2 and keep the rest of the data the same, is there a way of doing it in 1 line or do I have to go through each object in the supplies array through a for loop?

Also, what is the best way to automatically set 1 property to the same value? eg. If a user clicks id:1 ("All") then every other id will have the same checked value of all?